# Flowing from a thin client (web browser) to an installed and running application

Tags: java, web-applications, legacy-code, thick-client, thin-client

So I am working an a large scale application. We are in the process of moving from an installed java application to a web based application. During the transition release(s) we need the ability to bring up certain screens on the locally installed (and presumed running) application.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I've looked at custom URL handlers and some kind of messaging system, but neither of those seemed feasible for a large, dynamic number of clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using JMS, having the java application subscribe to a topic.  Then the server can fire off a message to the JMS topic, which is interpreted by the java app to open a particular screen?

Comment: How would you associate the message to a specific client machine?

Comment: This suggestion is a good idea, when using a discriminator, as specified above.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say use a message selector, but I was looking up the performance on it.  Seems it will be ok, depending on your app, so you should test it, of course.